# Arduino serial message with unknown length

Tags: c, arduino

How can I store the result of `Serial.readBytesUntil(character, buffer, length)` in a buffer while I don't know the length of the incoming message ?

Comment: Allocate a huge buffer, resize it afterwards, (if you need to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little code that makes use of `realloc()` to keep growing your buffer. You will have to `free()` when you're done with `buf`.

```
int length = 8;
char * buf = malloc(length);
int total_read = 0;

total_read = Serial.readBytesUntil(character, buf, length);
while(length == total_read) {
    length *= 2;
    buf = realloc(buf, length);
    // Bug in this line:
    // total_read += Serial.readBytesUntil(character, buf+total_read, length);
    // Should be
    total_read += Serial.readBytesUntil(character, buf+total_read, length-total_read);
}
```

*Edit: fixed a bug where `readBytesUntil` would have read off the end of `buf` by reading `length` bytes instead of `length-total_read` bytes.

Comment: @guiomie Bug in here, should only be reading `length-total_read` bytes, not `length`.

Answer (score 1):

make the buffer big enough for the message. Don't know the maximum length of the message? Use length to control the characters read, then continue reading until character encountered.

```
int bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil(character, buffer, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a buffer that is just smaller than the remaining RAM and use that. The call to find the remaining ram (as I've posted elsewhere) is:

```
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v; 
  int fr = (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval); 
  Serial.print("Free ram: ");
  Serial.println(fr);
}
```

Regardless, you should make sure you only read into as much RAM as you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is that when a program reads serial bytes it typically does NOT store them verbatim.  Rather, the program examines each byte and determines what action to take next.  This logic is typically implemented as Finite State Machine.

So, what does your specific serial stream represent?  Can it be analyzed in sequential chunks? For example: "0008ABCDEFGH" says that 8 chars follow the 4 character length field.  In this silly example your code would read 4 chars, then know how much space to allocate for the rest of the serial stream!